# How to Redirect URLs to a certain URL Django Regex

Tags: python, django, string, redirect

In my URLs.py, I'm setting my URL like this

```
url(r'^mobile/$', views.mobile, name='mobile')
```

Navigating to `localhost:8000/mobile` works as expected but if typed in the URL: `localhost:8000/mobile/hello/world/234234hjhf8sc3` it should redirect to `localhost:8000/mobile`
however this does not happen because my regex is incorrect (I'm not sure)

How could I do this/what is the correct regex to do this?

Another example would be `localhost:8000/mobile/send/help/as792lp` should redirect to
`localhost:8000/mobile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a [**`RedirectView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) to redirect any URL tat starts with a `mobile/` to the `mobile` view:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

url(r'^mobile/$', views.mobile, name='mobile')
url(r'^mobile/.+$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('mobile')))
```

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.

Comment: This would redirect the view but wouldn't a better approach be to redirect the URL itself to the '/mobile' ?

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy: what is the difference between the two. If you visit a URL like `/mobile/hello/world/234234hjhf8sc3`, it will return a HTTP 302 (redirect) to `/mobile/`, and then another view is triggered to render the content.

Comment: Using your method, I am getting a django.urls.exception.NoReverseMatch error. It seems the reverse for 'mobile' is not found and it is not a valid view or pattern name

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy: did you specify an `app_name` in the `urls.py?

Comment: Yes I did, it's listed as "development"

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy: then you should change it to `reverse_lazy('development:mobile')`.